# how can find MacId that presents more than 6 hours in a day

Tags: r, time

I wanna find the macid that attend more than 6 hourse and delete it from data.a way is find maximum and minimum detections time and delete it if it be more than 6 hours.but I want a simple way with R,
the data frame is like this.please see the picture to find out what did I say. 
[image]

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: In addition to Jaap's comment, please also post what you have tried so far, and where exactly you got stuck. Cheers